# How do I change the position of an html input using CSS

Tags: css

I'm new to this, so I apologice if the questions are stupid.

I have some code I inherited that I need to customize. I have an input defined in my html file:

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <input id="homeIcon" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

I also have this in my html:

```
<div id="header">
        <div style="float: left;">
            <div id="headerTitle">
                My Website
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

In the CSS I want to decide where to place this home icon. I want it to appear in the header to the right of the headerTitle.

Can I use the CSS to move an html element so that it appears in another div?
I managed to change the location within the current div - but not move it to an entirely new place.

Thanks,
Rocky

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to relocate elements using CSS (absolute positioning and other stuff that will break your layout).

CSS is just for visual representation of elements, so use HTML to change elements position

```
<div id="header">
    <input id="homeIcon" type="hidden" value="true"/>
    <div id="headerTitle">
        My Website
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I moved it in the div but it's still not showing up. The header is generated in a javascript file:

Comment: Thanks. I moved it in the div but it's still not showing up. The header is generated in a javascript file and perhaps I didn't add it correctly:
<code>
this._layout = new Ext.Viewport({
 layout: 'border',
 margins: '0 0 0 0',
 items: [ this._contentPanel,
new Ext.Panel({
 id: 'north-panel',
 border: false,
 region: 'north',
height: 100px,
 items: [
 {
 el:'header',
  border:false,
 xtype: 'box',
 hidden: (!showHeader),
height: 60px
 },
 {
 hidden: (!showHomeIcon),
iconCls: 'homeIcon',
 tooltip: 'Home',
tooltipType: 'title',
 scope: this,
handler: this._onClick_home_icon
},
</code>

Answer (score -1):

hello Rocky using css you can not move the element to another div but you can "over lap on the div area" so look like you put them to another div.using **position**

Comment: Setting `position: relative;` will do nothing. `position: relative; left: -4654px;` will move element.

Comment: ya you can right they need to study about the "position" i hope you can get my point.....i didn't say you can use only position....they neet to study about position